# SQL Server can not connect remotely from internet

Tags: sql-server

I have some instances in my server :

```
[IP_ADDRESS]\SQL2014 (Instance 1)
[IP_ADDRESS]\SQL2005 (Instance 2)
[IP_ADDRESS] (Instance 3)
```

And I want to make them online. I have set up my router to forward port 1433 and 1434 to My Server. I have also tried with remote dekstop and it's working fine with my public IP. I have port 1433 and 1434 opened in firewall and it's working fine when doing sql remotely using management studio using local IP.

But the problem is I can not connect to my server (SQL Server) using public IP but remote dekstop working good with public IP.

Have tried port checker with online checker and port 3389 is opened but 1433 and 1434 is closed.

Have tried disable antivirus and windows firewall and still can not connect.

**UPDATE 1**

I can connect to [IP_PUBLIC] (Instance 1) now but can not connect to [IP_PUBLIC]\SQL2014 (Instance 2 and 3)) using public IP

Error message for IP_PUBLIC\SQL2014 is : (Instance 2 and 3)

> a network related or instance error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to sql server. The server was not found or not accessible

**UPDATE 2**

After Restarting the Server and router port 1433 is opened now but still can not connect to IP_PUBLIC\SQL2014 (instance 2 and 3), Connecting using IP_LOCAL\SQL2014 is ok.

**UPDATE 3**

I try to install an instance in another server with "IP_PUBLIC\INSTANCE_NAME". It seems "IP_PUBLIC\INSTANCE_NAME" doesn't work with public IP. It is working fine with default instance name.

"IP_LOCAL\INSTANCE_NAME" is working good also using Local IP

Is there any possible caused by this? Port Forwarding or maybe how to call it if using public IP?

Note :
Windows Server 2008 R2
SQL Server 2014

Comment: have u enabled TCP/IP in ur sql configuration manager?

Comment: Did you enable the remote connection for sql server?

Comment: @AwaisMahmood : Yes, and its working fine using local IP

Comment: whats the error message?? is ur sql server running?

Comment: @SankarRaj : Yes is is enabled, now I can connect to [IP_ADRESS] but still can not connect to another instances [IP_ADDRESS]\SQL2014

Comment: @AwaisMahmood : Added to my question. Thank you.

Comment: that might be bcoz ur server is not running.. check in config manager.. is it running??

Comment: @AwaisMahmood : I can connect to IP_LOCAL\SQL2014

Comment: Have you entered your IP_PUBLIC in TCP/IP?

Comment: try accessing it at different allowed port. IP_PUBLIC\SQL2014,[portname]

Comment: @Hemal : How I can do that? FYI, Instance 1 "without SQL2014" can connect now but can't for Instance 2 and 3.

Comment: @AwaisMahmood : It doesn't work. I try to install an instance in another server with "IP_PUBLIC\INSTANCE_NAME". It seems "IP_PUBLIC\INSTANCE_NAME" doesn't work with public IP. It is working fine with default instance name. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried with some servers using named instance and looks like it is just work's with default instance.

I give up and decided making 1 instance per server.

Answer (score 1):

Please check you Firewall setting where you install SQL server. Firewall must have to allow SQL server for incoming and outgoing connection/data.